# PhpStorm. Проблема с комментированием строк

Tags: phpstorm

Добрый день!
Подскажите, можно ли как-то отключить перевод каретки на следующую строку при использовании сочетания "Ctrl/Cmd + /"? 
Хотелось бы, что бы оно работало так же как и в Sublime Text

Comment: Line comment CMD + / Ctrl + / Добавить строчный комментарий
Block comment CMD + Shift + / Ctrl + Shift + / Добавить блочный комментарий

Comment: Это не совсем то, о чем я спрашиваю...просто после нажатия Cmd + /, строка комментируется и при этом каретка (курсор) переходит на следующую строку, вот этот переход мне бы и хотелось отключить, если это возможно